# What is the maximum speed of the particle?

Tags: calculus

A particle is moving in the plane so that its position at time $t$, $(x(t),y(t))$, satisfies $\begin{cases} x(t) = \sin(t) \\ y(t)=\sin(3t)\end{cases}$

What is the maximum speed of the particle?

---

I don't know any formula that would help me on this problem.

Comment: Do you know how to find the velocity vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity of the particle is the vector ${\bf v}(t) = (\dot{x}(t), \dot{y}(t))$ and its speed is just $|{\bf v}(t)|$:

$$
{\bf v}(t) = (\cos t, 3\cos 3 t)
$$

With this you can calculate the speed

$$
v(t) = (\cos^2 t + 9\cos^2 3t)^{1/2}
$$

You need to find the maximum value of $v(t)$, can you take it from here?

Comment: It is easier to differentiate $v^2 (t)$.